# Is it possible to combine two conditions in switch case for Bash script?

Tags: bash

Suppose I want to read two inputs `x` and `y`, and as per values of them, I want to execute a switch case in Bash script.

Say the four combinations of inputs are:

1. `x=0`, `y=0`,
2. `x=0`, `y=1`,
3. `x=1`, `y=0`,
4. `x=1`, `y=1`.

But I don't know how to do it using script. I have tried the code but it's getting syntax error. Is it possible to combine two conditions in switch case for Bash script?

```
echo "enter x"
read x

echo "enter y"
read y

case "$x" "$y" in
    "zero" "zero") echo "condtion 1"
    ;;
    "zero" "one") echo "conditon 2"
    ;;
    "one" "zero" ) echo "condition 3"
    ;;
    "one" "one") echo "condition 4"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is about pattern matching, check this out:

```
$ case "a" in
>       b) echo fail;;
>       a) echo ok  ;;
> esac
ok

$ case "b" in
>       b) echo fail;;
>       a) echo ok  ;;
> esac
fail
```

So you just need to pass a pattern to the case. Which in your case could be like this:

```
read -p "enter x(0|1): " x
read -p "enter y(0|1): " y
    
case "$x$y" in
       00) echo "condition 1";;
       01) echo "condition 2";;
       10) echo "condition 3";;
       11) echo "condition 4";;
esac
```

And a separator is needed for a better readability(mostly).

```
case "$x|$y" in
       0|0) echo "condition 1";;
       0|1) echo "condition 2";;
       1|0) echo "condition 3";;
       1|1) echo "condition 4";;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

You can think of `$x$y` as a binary number.

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p 'enter x: ' x
read -p 'enter y: ' y

case $((2#$x$y)) in
  0) echo 'condition 1';;
  1) echo 'condition 2';;
  2) echo 'condition 3';;
  3) echo 'condition 4';;
esac
```

This works up to 64 different states:

```
$ echo $((64#11))
65
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a separator:

```sh
echo "enter x"
read x

echo "enter y"
read y

SEP=":::"
case "${x}${SEP}${y}" in
    "zero${SEP}zero") echo "condtion 1"
    ;;
    "zero${SEP}one") echo "conditon 2"
    ;;
    "one${SEP}zero" ) echo "condition 3"
    ;;
    "one${SEP}one") echo "condition 4"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd invoke `read` with `-r` and use a newline as the separator though.